# How does .Net webservice requests distribute in the IIS connection pool?

Tags: .net, http, iis, connection-pooling

We're running a web site on Win 2003 server .Net 4.0 and IIS 6.0. This websites makes many webservice requests to several other servers. We're getting timeout issues on these requests.

By using Debug Diagnostic Tool on dumps from the server, we have confirmed that the requests seem to be waiting for a connection out - not the other end to respond:

> The following threads in XXXXXXXX-app-pool are attempting to make an
>   HttpWebRequest, however they do *not* appear to be waiting on the
>   remote server to respond (eg. not 'on the wire'). One or more of these
>   requests are exceeding its maximum number of available connections.*
>
> HttpRequest URI:http://certainserver.somwhere.com/certainwebservice.asmx
>   ServicePoint - ConnectionLimit:24 CurrentConnections:24

Fair enough. So how does the connection pool actually work? Why are we getting this problems now? Code base is mostly unchanged - server infrastructure IS changed - more servers.

Is this connection pool the same pool of connections as sql connections will use?

When does it pick a "new" connection?

When is a request out queued in an "existing" connection? Are they ever?

If a certain page in the website has to call two different webservices to show the front page, how many connections will be used? Two? Does it matter if the two webservices are on the same or different servers?

What if there are 5 visitors at pretty much the same time? Will it try to use 2 x 5 connections, or is there gonna be one connection pr "unique" webservice?

I find it hard to search this, because there is so many kinds of connection, and most matches on connection pooling issues is usally about sql connections - not webservice requests.

The webserver has two cores and max limit of 24 connection (default setting of 12 pr core).

Comment: If I am not wrong , the max connections for each website within an ApplicationDomain is quite huge. Check the settings for your Website or App.

Comment: That is incoming connections to the web site, isn't it? I'm talking about max number of httpwebrequests that the website can make further out.

Comment: the max no of requests that your app can make will again depend on the Web Server you're trying to hit. If the web service host allows only one request at a time , so further requests would be queued. So not getting a response from a particular webservice will be related to the host's code.

Comment: Thank you for your input on the problem, however my question is about how the connection pool work. :)

Comment: I can give a lil blunt answer for that ... iis 6 is diff from it's previous versions ... you can maintain separate AppPools . An AppPool can have mutiple websites/webapps within it.... AppPools cannot share data between 2 AppPools and hence there is no vice-versa effect. Within each AppPool is a worker process. Each worker process will spawn multiple worker processes within itself for multiple requests hence no 2 requests are queued but they can share resources... But any effects on the AppPool will effect all the worker processes within it